# not able to start the session for the selenium with python

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ubuntu-18.04

I am facing an issue while running simple selenium python automation program where could not able to solve the main issue.

the problem is either with the chrome driver or else , did not getting the root cause.

I have install the google-chrome and chrome-driver with the below commands in my Linux machine,

linux machine : Linux 5.4.0-73-generic #82~18.04.1-Ubuntu

###### Install google

`sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable`

- google chrome version : Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77

###### Install chormedriver

`wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip`

- install chromedriver into the specific location and give path of it.

after that execute the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = True
chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Application/chromedriver',options=chromeOptions)

# Navigate to page
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.title)

driver.quit()
```

after that below error receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sly_test.py", line 12, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Application/chromedriver',options=chromeOptions)
File "/home/sysadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/home/sysadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/home/sysadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/home/sysadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/sysadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
(Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

- Can anyone please guide me to run selenium with python smoothly on linux machine?

Comment: Did you install  correct version of Selenium?

Comment: yes I have install latest version of selenium, it's 3.141.0

Comment: you have `Chrome 91.x.x` but you use `chromedriver 90.x.x` - you may have to use `chromedriver 91.x.x`. See the newests `chromedriver` on https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Comment: this code works for me on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) with theses same versions of Chrome, chromedriver, Selenium.

Comment: your error shows `chrome=90.0.4430.212` - so maybe it tries to use different version then you expect. You should check what version is executed as default browser for HTML files.

Comment: @furas, I have tried to install latest chromedriver which match 91.x.x.x , in that case I got an different error of version not match, `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91 Current browser version is 90.0.4430.21`   not sure why it is taking an 90.0.4430.212 version.

Comment: as I said you before - older version can be used as default browser. Click on any file .html and see what browser it opens. There are two similar browser: `Google Chrome` and `Chromium` - if you have `Chromium` as default browser then even if you install `Google Chrome` it still will use `Chromium`. If you right click on .html then you should have menu with `"open with ..."` and you can select what program will be default browser. OR maybe you should update [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) instead of `Google Chrome`. ie. `apt install chromium`

Comment: @furas, I have checked and default one is google chrome. I have tried to uninstall everything and install it again with install.sh file from this [link](https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5), which worked perfectly for 8-9 times after again facing the same issue. but this time my headless version is `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.77)` , any idea?

Comment: I have no idea but first I would try without all these options to see browser and see if it works correclty. You should also check in porcesses if older process is still runing - `ps aux | grep chrom` - because it may block access. And this may need to kill process manually - ie. `pkill -9 -f chrom`

Comment: and when you check what is default browser then also check version (somewhere in menu "help" or "about browser")

Comment: @furas, Thanks for your response, as you mentioned in second last comment, due to older process ongoing , I am getting this error. After kill all the process as you mention I am able to executes it smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some efforts and help , I have tried to uninstall everything and install it again with install.sh file from this [link](https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5). Later on got to know that my chrome older process is ongoing that's why it is not able to create a new session and throws an error `Message: Session not created`.
Finally, kill all process of chrome with `pkill -9 -f chrom` able to execute selenium with python code without any error.